# Can't use dates in Gnuplot.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnuplot

I'm trying to make a plot using the `Gnuplot.py` python module, but I get a `ValueError` since the dates are getting turned into integers for some reason. (This issue doesn't occur using Gnuplot on the command-line.)

MWE:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Gnuplot

dates   = ['2022-04-12', '2022-04-16', '2022-04-18']
amounts = ['585',        '405',        '345']

g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(persist=True)
g('set xdata time')
g('set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"')
g('set format x "%Y-%m-%d"')
d = Gnuplot.Data(dates, amounts, with_='lp', u='1:2')
g.plot(d)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/folder/./test.py", line 12, in <module>
    d = Gnuplot.Data(dates, amounts, with_='lp', u='1:2')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Gnuplot/PlotItems.py", line 558, in Data
    data = utils.float_array(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Gnuplot/utils.py", line 30, in float_array
    return numpy.asarray(m, numpy.float32)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2022-04-12'
```

Comment: what error are you getting the full traceback?

Comment: @alexpdev Added the traceback above.

Comment: The reason it isn't working is because the first two arguments to `Gnuplot.Data` are expected to be numpy arrays, or a datrastrcture that can converted to an array of numpy floats, both of the arrays you are passing are string arrays